# Move dictionary elements to list in list of dictionary

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
information = [{
     "info": {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "M."
    },
     "code": "1"
    },

    {
     "info": {
         "first_name": "Sara",
         "last_name": "B. R."
     },
      "code": "2"
    }]
```

I want to convert above list as follow:

```
information = [{
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "M.",
    "code": "1"
},

{
    "first_name": "Sara",
    "last_name": "B. R.",
    "code": "2"
}]
```

I used nested loops like this(, but it's not `clean code`:

```
for item in information:
    if 'info' in item.keys():
         for key in item.values():
             ...
```

What is best practice?

Comment: In particular, you haven't done anything to build a new dict.  This is straightforward dict access and rebuilding, but you've printed the values rather than making a new dict.  We need you to clean up your code to a single problem; otherwise, we're simply writing the entire conversion for you, which is out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate through each list items and define a temporary dictionary, then iterate through the dictionary item, if the value of the dictionary is an instance of `dict` update the temporary dictionary with the value inside the internal dictionary, else just assign the current key/value parint, finally append it to the resulting list.

```py
result = []

for item in infromation:
    temp = {}
    for key,value in item.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            temp.update(value)
        else:
            temp[key] = value
    result.append(temp)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
[{'code': '1', 'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'M.'},
 {'code': '2', 'first_name': 'Sara', 'last_name': 'B. R.'}]
```